# What is equivalent of GNU split in python?

Tags: python, bash

I'm migrating some of old bash scripts to python, both for utilitar and educational purposes. In Bash i'd use something like

```
cat dir/*csv|split -n5 -d --filter="gzip -c - >$FILE.gz" -L20000 - combined/part-
```

and get directory with number of archived files with correct number of records each.

I'm wondering what library or approach in Python would behave in a similar way to [gnu split](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html)?

Answer (score -2):

python has a default split method for string type.
for example:
msg = "this:is:a:message"
result = msg.split(":")

result will be a list as follow:
["this", "is", "a", "message"]

Comment: Don't confuse between gnu cut and gnu split, they're very different tools

Comment: Or rather, the program `split` is wildly different from Python's `split` method.